# Does uploading a paper to arxiv with the same title but different author list affect citations?

Tags: publications

I have a paper on the arxiv (v1) that I'd like to update to the most recent version (v2).  The author list has expanded since v1.  If I upload v2 with the new authors, will this affect the citations on google scholar or will the citations of v1 just carry over to v2?

Comment: The downvoter might want to explain..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search results on Google Scholar usually club together citations on different versions of the same article (see screenshot below). Moreover, since Google Scholar works with preprints, and preprint servers like arXiv have options to add or replace author names, in my opinion, this will not affect your citation count. However, make sure that when your paper gets published, the author list is updated in arXiv as well.

[image]